# Azure VM Disconnects after changing DNS

Tags: rdp, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

I have an public Azure VM instance running Windows 10 . I changed the DNS to Google DNS and I loose  RDP connection. Why?

Answer (score 0):

**While changing the DNS servers, please follow below steps:**

- Changing the DNS servers to Google DNS servers can be done via ***Azure portal or PowerShell.***
- From ***Azure Portal***, Navigate to your VNET, click on DNS servers and enter the DNS server IPs.
- After doing changes to DNS, Virtual Machine need a ***reboot***. Make sure to reboot the VM.
- This change can be done on the ***NIC of Virtual Machine*** not on the OS level.
- ***Resize the Virtual Machine***, if reboot doesn't restore connectivity. This should return the RDP and the DNS entry you defined.
- Try ***redeploying*** the Virtual machine.
- Otherwise, Try resetting the ***Remote Desktop configuration.***
- Try Checking the Network Security Group rules.
- Try ***Resetting the NIC*** for the VM.

To know more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Lost connectivity to Azure VM after changing DNS to automatically obtain DNS - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/462177/lost-connectivity-to-azure-vm-after-changing-dns-t.html?msclkid=34413dceb97a11ecaba8b6f16e58ce13).

[Cannot connect with RDP to a Windows VM in Azure - Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection)

[VM getting disconnected after changing preferred DNS IP (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/38c8f3b8-c0db-4912-bfc3-e625a5babdcb/vm-getting-disconnected-after-changing-preferred-dns-ip?msclkid=9a498693b97911ecb48d55bc3de74554).

[Change VM DNS Servers - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/63409/change-vm-dns-servers.html).